# How to earn from the third party ads in exo player (android)?

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer

I want to add third party  Ads in exoplayer integrated in my android app. So which type of ads can I integrate so that I can earn from them just like earning from admobs.
One more question can I integrate admobs in exoplayer and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try IMA sdk by google for video ads
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/client-side

You can create your personal ads using VAST Tag
https://support.google.com/admanager/table/9749596?hl=en

Comment: i have added the sample ad tag to test the ad but how will I recieve the ads automatically

Comment: please tell me what next I have to do?

Comment: sorry for late reply, you need to create AdSense account for real ads